# Object Recursion and flatten the objects in a List

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, data-structures, linked-list

Looking for a best solution for the object recursion problem. Below is the example:

**Class:**

```
public class SomeObject {
      private List<SomeObject> objects;
}
```

Data:

**Input:**
   SomeObject has List of objects and every Object in list is of SomeObject Type and has list inside them. (Recursive in nature)

Requirement is to flatten them and put them in a single arraylist.

The flatten List should have all the SomeObject types.

Can anyone suggest what's the best way to handle this case. Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using Java 8, You might consider doing it this way.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass {

    static List<SomeObject> flatList = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

    public static void flatten(SomeObject object) {
        if (object != null ){
            if( object.getObjects() != null && !object.getObjects().isEmpty()) {
            for (SomeObject o : object.getObjects()) {
               flatten(o);
               flatList.add(object);
            }           
        }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SomeObject o1 = new SomeObject("1");

        SomeObject o2 = new SomeObject("2");

        SomeObject o3 = new SomeObject("3");

        SomeObject o4 = new SomeObject("4");

        o1.addObject(o2);
        o2.addObject(o3);
        o3.addObject(o4);

        flatten(o1);
        for (SomeObject obj : flatList){
            System.out.println(obj.getObjectName());
        }


    }

}

 class SomeObject {

     String objectName = "";

     public SomeObject(String name) {
        this.objectName = name;
    }
      private List<SomeObject> objects = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

    public List<SomeObject> getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }

    public void setObjects(List<SomeObject> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public void addObject(SomeObject o){
        objects.add(o);     
    }

    public String getObjectName() {
        return objectName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make recursion, the method for a given object would require to :

- add itself : *add to list*
- ask its children to do same : *collect all children `getAllChildren()`*

---

```
public class Foo {

    private String s;    
    private List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>();    
    public Foo(String a) {
        s = a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo a = new Foo("a");
        Foo b = new Foo("b");
        Foo c = new Foo("c");
        Foo d = new Foo("d");
        Foo e = new Foo("e");
        a.fooList.add(b);
        b.fooList.add(c);
        c.fooList.add(e);
        a.fooList.add(d);
        List<Foo> list = a.getAllChildren();
        System.out.println(list);             
    }

    private List<Foo> getAllChildren() {
        List<Foo> l = fooList.stream().flatMap(elt -> elt.getAllChildren().stream())
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
        l.add(this);
        return l;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return s; }
}
```

*Input Structure :*

```
a-b-c-d
 \   \
  e   f
```

*Output List :*

```
[d, f, c, b, e, a]
```